# Display loop response in loader modal while return the intermediate page in java

Tags: java, html

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getMusterRollDateBasedNew", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getMusterRollDateBasedNew(EmployeeReportsModel employeeReportsModel) {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    String tablePrefix = "at_hr_logs_";
    String loopresponse = null;
    try {
        String fromdate = employeeReportsModel.getReportFromDt();
        String todate = employeeReportsModel.getReportToDt();
        Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(fromdate);
        Date date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(todate);
        SimpleDateFormat sdfDestination = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String fromdate1 = sdfDestination.format(date1);
        String todate1 = sdfDestination.format(date2);
        employeeReportsModel.setReportFromDt(fromdate1);
        employeeReportsModel.setReportToDt(todate1);
        // get dates between two dates

        List<EmployeeReportsModel> datesList = employeeReportsMapper.getDatesBetweenTwoDates(employeeReportsModel);
        mv.addObject("datesList", datesList);

        List<EmployeeReportsModel> dayAndMonth = employeeReportsMapper.getDayandMonthBetweenTwoDates(employeeReportsModel);
        mv.addObject("dayAndMonth", dayAndMonth);

        ArrayList<Integer> datesList2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int step;
        for (step = datesList.size(); step <= 31; step++) {
            datesList2.add(step + 1);
        }
        mv.addObject("datesList2", datesList2);

        List<EmployeeReportsModel> empList = employeeReportsMapper.getMusterSheetDateEmpList(employeeReportsModel);
        mv.addObject("empList", empList);
        int loopCounter = 0;
        for (EmployeeReportsModel x : empList) {

            loopCounter += 1;
            //System.out.println("loopCounter is..." + loopCounter);
            employeeReportsModel.setEmpCode(x.getEmpCode());
            employeeReportsModel.setEmpName(x.getEmpName());
            employeeReportsModel.setDepartmentId(x.getDepartmentId());
            employeeReportsModel.setCompanyId(x.getCompanyId());

            int insert = employeeReportsMapper.setEmployeeCodes(employeeReportsModel);          

              loopresponse =  loopCounter + "/" + empList.size();
             System.out.println("loopresponse is..." + loopresponse);

            int counter = 0;
            for (EmployeeReportsModel y : datesList) {

                counter += 1;
                employeeReportsModel.setReportFromDt(y.getReportFromDt());
                String[] parts = y.getReportFromDt().split("-");
                String part1 = parts[0]; // 004
                String part2 = parts[1]; // 034556
                String part3 = parts[2];

                String tableName = tablePrefix + part1 + '_' + part2;
                employeeReportsModel.setDynamicTableName(tableName);
                // define two strings
                String columnFirstName = "day";
                Integer columnSecondName = counter;
                // concatenate the strings
                String columnName = columnFirstName + columnSecondName;

                employeeReportsModel.setColumnName(columnName);
                EmployeeReportsModel attdLogs = employeeReportsMapper.getLogTimings(employeeReportsModel);
                employeeReportsModel.setDay1(attdLogs.getDay1());
                employeeReportsMapper.updateEmployeeLogs(employeeReportsModel);

            }
        }
        List<EmployeeReportsModel> allLogs = employeeReportsMapper.getMusterSheetAllLogs(employeeReportsModel);
        mv.addObject("allLogs", allLogs);

        employeeReportsMapper.truncateTable(employeeReportsModel);
        // employeeReportsMapper.dynamicCreationofTablesMuster();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        employeeReportsMapper.truncateTable(employeeReportsModel);
    }
    mv.setViewName("/" + moduleName + "/employeeMusterRollBasedOnDateInterNew");
    return mv;

}
```

Now we need get  **loopresponse** in browser lodar modal. for every loop we get the response in between loop execution.can I set **loopresponse** in existing below modal

here loopresponse = numOfEmp/loopCount.

so need set as below

example:loopresponse 1/15,2/15,3/15,4/15,5/15,6/15,7/15,8/15,9/15,10/15,11/15,12/15,13/15,14/15,15/15.

we need to set in below lodar modal

```
 <div id="loadarModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1"
                style="padding-left: 200px; padding-top: 150px;">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <img
                            src="/<s:message code="projectName"></s:message>/resources/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
                        <font style="color: white;">loading...Please Wait</font>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="loadarDiv" hidden>
                <div align="center">
                    <img
                        src="/<s:message code="projectName"></s:message>/resources/images/ajax-loader(Black).gif" />
                    <font>loading...Please Wait</font>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Side note: Don’t use the long outdated classes `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Do use the modern `LocalDate` inside your employee report model so you  don’t need to parse each time you take it out.

Comment: okay thank you ,but here I want set response to browser every time through out the loop